# Is it possible to connect VM as a USB device

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I have a usb machine in VirtualBox with WP Phone 8.0 installed. What I want is to emulate connection from the VM to the host as a USB device.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so. Virtual machines are designed to work as USB hosts. Maybe somebody has an answer for you, but you should mention what VM software you're using. You have tags both for VirtualBox and VMware, do you have both set up?

Comment: Sorry, only VirtualBox

Comment: what exactly will you do - am i right that you try to connect your virtuallized Phone to the PC as you would do it with a real phone? - if yes, then i think you don't have a Chance to do that. but to be shure you should better ask this question on the virtualbox forum or mailinglist https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Community